# Primos y tablas de multiplicar

Tags: php

No consigo hacer andar este código. Se trata de ir listando los números primos y no primos definidos en un rango mostrando la tabla de multiplicar de los que son primos. A ver si alguien me aclara sobre como definir el código.

```
<?php


for($i=3;$i<=7;$i++)
{
    if(primo($i))
         echo '<div style="color:green;font-weight:bold;">' .  " ".$i." es un primo ". "<br/>"   ;

         echo "<table border=5 px  hight:200px width= 200px cellspacing=5  cellpadding=5 display: block   >";
         echo "<tr><th> Tabla del $tabla </th></tr>";
         {   
   // generamos la tabla 
     elseif(primo($i)) 
        for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) 
     {

        echo "<tr><td align=center>$tabla por $i </td>
              <td  align=center style=background-color:green > ". ($tabla*$i) . "</td>
             </tr>";
     }

    else{
        echo '<div style="color:red"; font-weight:bold;>' . " ".$i." NO es número primo " . "<br/>";


}




function primo($num)

{
    $cont=0;

    // Funcion que recorre todos los numero desde el 2 hasta el valor recibido

    for($i=2;$i<=$num;$i++)
    {
        if($num%$i==0)
        {
            # Si se puede dividir por algun numero mas de una vez, no es primo
            if(++$cont>1)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;

}

?>
```

Comment: La variable $tabla de donde la sacas? que valor tiene?

Comment: ahí es principalmente donde no consigo ver solución porque para que me haga la tabla de multiplicar de los números que sí son primos tendré que asignarle a la variable tabla el valor de i, no?

Comment: NO entiendo muy bien, aparte de obtener cual es numero primo y cual no que más necesitas? saber de que tabla de multilplicar es?

Comment: No, necesito que me muestre la tabla de multiplicar de los números que sí son primos.

Comment: a ver si te entiendo bien, si 3 es numero primero tiene que decir 3 es primo y la tabla de multiplicar es de 3 no?

Comment: exacto, y así con todos los números del rango.

Comment: Tu código, es un desastre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, modifique tu código ya que tenias un desorden en cuento a la hora de armar la tabla y en cuanto a la lógica, logré optimizar la función de los números primos y la tabla, puedes ver el código funcionando [aquí](http:////phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%5Cnfor($i=3;$i%3C=7;$i%20%20)%7B%5Cn%20if(primo($i))%7B%5Cn%20echo%20'%3Ctable%20border=%221%22%20width=%22200px%22%20cellspacing=%220%22%20cellpadding=%220%22%3E%5Cn%20%3Ctr%3E%5Cn%20%3Cth%20style=%22color:green;font-weight:bold;%22%20colspan=%222%22%3E%20'.$i.'%20es%20un%20primo.%3C/th%3E%5Cn%20%3C/tr%3E';%5Cn%20for($j=1;%20$j%3C10;%20$j%20%20)%7B%5Cn%20echo%20'%3Ctr%3E%5Cn%20%3Ctd%20align=center%3E'.$i.'%20por%20'.$j.'%20%3C/td%3E%5Cn%20%3Ctd%20align=center%20style=%22background-color:green%22%20%3E%20'.%20($i*$j)%20.%20'%3C/td%3E%5Cn%20%3C/tr%3E';%5Cn%20%7D%5Cn%20echo%20'%3C/table%3E';%5Cn%20%7Delse%7B%5Cn%20echo%20'%3Ctable%20style=%22border=5px;hight:200px;%22%20width=%22200px%22%20cellspacing=%225%22%20cellpadding=%225%22%3E%5Cn%20%3Ctr%3E%5Cn%20%3Ctd%20align=center%3E$i%20por%20$i%20%3C/td%3E%5Cn%20%3Ctd%20align=center%20style=%22color:red;%20font-weight:bold;%22%3E%20'.$i.'%20NO%20es%20n%C3%BAmero%20primo%3C/td%3E%5Cn%20%3C/tr%3E%5Cn%20%3C/table%3E';%5Cn%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnfunction%20primo($num)%7B%5Cn%20$primo%20=%200;%5Cn%20for%20($b%20=%201;%20$b%20%3C%20$num;%20$b%20%20)%20%7B%5Cn%20if%20($num%20%25%20$b%20==%200)%20%7B%5Cn%20$primo%20%20;%5Cn%20%7D%5Cn%20%7D%5Cn%20if%20($primo%20%3E=%202)%20%7B%5Cn%20return%20false;%5Cn%20%7D%20else%20%7B%5Cn%20return%20true;%5Cn%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn?%3E%5Cn).

```
for($i=3;$i<=7;$i++){

  if(primo($i)){ 

    echo '<table border="1" width="200px" cellspacing="0"  cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <th style="color:green;font-weight:bold;" colspan="2"> '.$i.' es un primo.</th>
            </tr>';

    for($j=1; $j<10; $j++){
      echo '<tr>
              <td align=center>'.$i.' por '.$j.' </td>
              <td  align=center style="background-color:green" > '. ($i*$j) . '</td>
            </tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';

  }else{

     echo '<table style="border=5px;hight:200px;" width="200px" cellspacing="5"  cellpadding="5">
             <tr>
               <td align=center>$i por $i </td>
               <td  align=center style="color:red; font-weight:bold;"> '.$i.' NO es número primo</td>
             </tr>
           </table>';

  }

}


function primo($num){

  $primo = 0;

  for ($b = 1; $b < $num; $b++) {
    if ($num % $b == 0) {
        $primo++;
    }
  }

  if ($primo >= 2) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }

}


?>
```

Espero que sea lo que andas buscando.

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas repasar php y html. De verdad.

Tu código:

```
<?php


for($i=3;$i<=7;$i++)
{
    if(primo($i))
         echo '<div style="color:green;font-weight:bold;">' .  " ".$i." es un primo ". "<br/>"   ;

         echo "<table border=5 px  hight:200px width= 200px cellspacing=5  cellpadding=5 display: block   >";
         echo "<tr><th> Tabla del $tabla </th></tr>";
         {   
   // generamos la tabla 
     elseif(primo($i)) 
        for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) 
     {

        echo "<tr><td align=center>$tabla por $i </td>
              <td  align=center style=background-color:green > ". ($tabla*$i) . "</td>
             </tr>";
     }

    else{
        echo '<div style="color:red"; font-weight:bold;>' . " ".$i." NO es número primo " . "<br/>";


}




function primo($num)

{
    $cont=0;

    // Funcion que recorre todos los numero desde el 2 hasta el valor recibido

    for($i=2;$i<=$num;$i++)
    {
        if($num%$i==0)
        {
            # Si se puede dividir por algun numero mas de una vez, no es primo
            if(++$cont>1)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;

}

?>
```

**Errores:**

1. Todas las líneas donde aparece `$tabla` porque es una variable que
   nunca la defines.
2. Usar `i` en dos bucles `for` seguidos. El primer bucle incrementará `i`, pero el segundo también lo hará y al terminar la ejecución del segundo bucle, el valor de `i` no será el valor del primer bucle `for` sino del **segundo.**
3. Etiquetas html con formato o estilo sin comillas:  `echo "<table border=5 px  hight:200px width= 200px cellspacing=5  cellpadding=5 display: block   >";`y etiquetas no cerradas. Te falta `</div>` y `</table>` para cerrar el los `div` y `table` que creas.

No sé si hay más, pero cuando ya vi eso paré de contar. Tu código "arreglado" quedaría así:

```
<?php
    function primo($num){
        $cont=0;
        // Funcion que recorre todos los numero desde el 2 hasta el valor recibido
        for($i=2;$i<=$num;$i++){
            if(($num%$i)==0){
                // Si se puede dividir por algun numero mas de una vez, no es primo
                if(++$cont>1){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    for($i=3;$i<=7;$i++){
        if(primo($i)){
            echo "<table>";
            echo '<tr><th style="color:green"> '.$i." es primo</th></tr>";
            echo "<table border='5'>";
            echo "<tr><th> Tabla del ".$i."</th></tr>";
            // Generamos la tabla 
            for($k=0; $k<=10; $k++){
                echo '<tr><td align="center">'.$i." por ".$k.' </td>
                    <td  align="center" style="background-color:green"> '.($k*$i). "</td></tr>";
             }
             echo "</table>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<table>";
            echo '<tr><th style="color:red"> '.$i." no es primo</th></tr>";
            echo "</table>";
        }
        echo "<br/>";
    }
?>
```

Creo las `table` para mostrar si un número es primo o no en vez de div, para no tener que estar asignándole posiciones y eso, y queden directamente uno debajo del otro.

Comment: Muchas gracias, es verdad. Una pregunta ¿ Para introducir por teclado los números que conforman el rango,sería con los GET y POST, no ?

Comment: Podrías hacer un formulario que pida un rango de números, con dos tipo input, el usuario ingresaría por ejemplo en el primer input 3 y en el segundo 7, y daría como resultado lo de tu ejemplo